# How to find the interval between multiple dates in a single column conditioned on their group id using r?

Tags: r, date, datetime

So basically I have a dataframe called df. df has multiple columns but the ones I want to bring focus to are DT (a `POSIXct` variable) and CITY (a character variable). Each CITY has a varying number of entries in the DT column. I want to create a third column that is the interval between each chronological DT for each CITY respectively. So each city has its own individual set of dates and its own set of day intervals.

I created a subset of df for a more intuitive look at what I'm working with.

```
DT <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-11-02 20:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-02 19:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-02 20:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-03 19:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-03 19:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-04 19:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-05 19:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-05 19:00:00 CET",
"2019-11-05 20:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-06 19:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-06 20:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-06 20:30:00 CET",
"2019-11-06 19:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-06 19:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-08 19:30:00 CET",
"2019-11-08 20:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-08 20:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-08 19:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-08 19:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-08 19:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-09 20:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-10 21:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-10 19:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-10 18:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-10 21:00:00 CET", 
"2019-11-11 19:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-11 22:30:00 CET", 
"2019-11-12 21:00:00 CET",
"2019-11-12 19:00:00 CET" ))
CITY <- c("TOR", "ORL", "WAS", "DAL", "CLE", "WAS", "ATL", "CLE", "ORL", "ATL", "ORL", "DAL", "WAS", "TOR", "ATL", "DAL", "TOR", "ORL", "CLE", "WAS", "DAL", "TOR", "CLE", "ORL", "ATL", "DAL", "TOR", "ATL", "CLE")
df <- data.frame(DT, CITY)
df <- df %>% arrange(CITY)
df
```

The third column I created below is my desired outcome and the first two column are what I currently have.

```
days <- c(NA,1,2,2,2,NA,2,3,2,2,NA,3,2,1,2,NA,3,1,2,2,NA,4,2,2,1,NA,2,2,2)
df <- data.frame(df, days_since_last_entry)
df
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What would the expected outcome of your shared examples be? Something like `aggregate(DT ~ CITY, df, function(i)paste0(first(i), ' - ', last(i)))`?

Comment: I can see several ways to interpret your description, especially "each city has its own first date and last date and its own set of day intervals" which is in apparent  contradiction with "I want to create a third column that is the interval between each chronological DT for each CITY". The easiest way to clarify would be to give us the expected outcome for your small example. Good question and reproducible example though.

Comment: @asac-ReinstateMonica Thank you for pointing that out. Basically I would want a third column which lists the number of days since the last DT entry. What I meant by each CITY has its own start and end date is that each CITY has its own individual set of DT entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table); setDT(df)
df[, Diff := difftime(DT, shift(DT), units = 'days'), keyby = CITY]
```

**Result**

```
> df
                     DT CITY           Diff
 1: 2019-11-05 19:30:00  ATL        NA days
 2: 2019-11-06 19:30:00  ATL 1.0000000 days
 3: 2019-11-08 19:30:00  ATL 2.0000000 days
 4: 2019-11-10 21:00:00  ATL 2.0625000 days
 5: 2019-11-12 21:00:00  ATL 2.0000000 days
 6: 2019-11-03 19:30:00  CLE        NA days
 7: 2019-11-05 19:00:00  CLE 1.9791667 days
 8: 2019-11-08 19:00:00  CLE 3.0000000 days
 9: 2019-11-10 19:30:00  CLE 2.0208333 days
10: 2019-11-12 19:00:00  CLE 1.9791667 days
11: 2019-11-03 19:30:00  DAL        NA days
12: 2019-11-06 20:30:00  DAL 3.0416667 days
13: 2019-11-08 20:30:00  DAL 2.0000000 days
14: 2019-11-09 20:00:00  DAL 0.9791667 days
15: 2019-11-11 19:30:00  DAL 1.9791667 days
16: 2019-11-02 19:00:00  ORL        NA days
17: 2019-11-05 20:00:00  ORL 3.0416667 days
18: 2019-11-06 20:30:00  ORL 1.0208333 days
19: 2019-11-08 19:00:00  ORL 1.9375000 days
20: 2019-11-10 18:00:00  ORL 1.9583333 days
21: 2019-11-02 20:00:00  TOR        NA days
22: 2019-11-06 19:30:00  TOR 3.9791667 days
23: 2019-11-08 20:00:00  TOR 2.0208333 days
24: 2019-11-10 21:30:00  TOR 2.0625000 days
25: 2019-11-11 22:30:00  TOR 1.0416667 days
26: 2019-11-02 20:00:00  WAS        NA days
27: 2019-11-04 19:00:00  WAS 1.9583333 days
28: 2019-11-06 19:00:00  WAS 2.0000000 days
29: 2019-11-08 19:00:00  WAS 2.0000000 days
                     DT CITY           Diff

# Verifying against provided expected output
> df[, all.equal(round(Diff), days)]
[1] TRUE
```

If you want rounded and/or numeric entries in `Diff`, simply wrap `difftime` with `round(as.numeric())`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was unclear when I first asked the question. I am looking to display the interval of days between dates for each CITY's individual set of dates.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your expected output. Below is my solution:

```
DF <- data.frame(days = sapply(split(df,df$CITY), function(v) Reduce("-",Map(as.Date,c(tail(v["DT"],1)[[1]],head(v["DT"],1)[[1]])))))
```

which gives:

```
> DF
        days
ATL        7
CLE        9
DAL        8
ORL        8
TOR        9
WAS        6
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was unclear when I first asked the question. I am looking to display the interval of days between dates for each CITY's individual set of dates.